# Issues with a WP plugin menu system

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I'm attempting to create a simple menu layout for a plugin. This is my first attempt at creating a plugin so apologies for what probably an obvious mistake here. This is the code I have to create the menu

```
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_menu_page' );
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_submenu_page' );

function register_menu_page()
    {
    add_menu_page( 'Broughton Admin', 'Broughton Admin', 'manage_options', 'broughton-admin-page', 'broughton_admin_page' ); 
    }

function register_submenu_page() {
    add_submenu_page( 'broughton-admin-page', 'Upload XML', 'Upload XML', 'manage_options', 'upload-xml-page', 'upload_xml_page' ); 
    add_submenu_page( 'broughton-admin-page', 'Archive XML', 'Archive XML', 'manage_options', 'archive-xml-page', 'archive_xml_page' );

function broughton_admin_page()
    {
        echo '<p>Menu Page</p>';
    }

function upload_xml_page() 
    {
    echo '<p>Upload submenu page</p>';
    }

function archive_xml_page()
    {
    echo '<p>Archive subment page</p>';
    }
```

The code doesn't work, I just get a white screen when I attempt to login as an admin. The error log rather ambiguously reports: "syntax error, unexpected end of file". Can anyone see the issue here?

Comment: [Enable debugging](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)! It'll make developing so much easier. No more white screens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function is still open!

Add "}" at the end.

```
function register_submenu_page() {
  add_submenu_page( 'broughton-admin-page', 'Upload XML', 'Upload XML',        'manage_options', 'upload-xml-page', 'upload_xml_page' ); 
  add_submenu_page( 'broughton-admin-page', 'Archive XML', 'Archive XML', 'manage_options', 'archive-xml-page', 'archive_xml_page' );
}
```

Comment: This is awkward. I've been starting at that for 20 minutes convinced it was an error with the way I was passing values in the function calls. Thanks for that!